# how can PC Chrome debug iOS env variables, like env(safe-area-inset-bottom)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, css-variables

I know iOS simulator which open an iOS iPhoneX can debug env variables, but I want to use chrome dev tools to invoke css variable.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for an answer as well. I don't think there's a way to do it without the actual iOS app. Because you really need that floating address bar to test the safe area.

So the best two options in my opinion are something like Ngrok or a tool like Browser Stack.